# Active Directory memberOf LDAP syntax

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to add a user (from LDAP to Active Directory) to more than one group.
The command `memberOf: CN=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=AAA,DC=AAA` is for only one and I want to add a second one immediatly after the first; e.g.:
 `memberOf: CN=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=AAA,DC=AAA` **and** `CN=BBB,OU=BBB,DC=BBB,DC=BBB`

Comment: How do you want to add this user? Using an admin tool (-> then this question belongs on [Serverfault.com](http://Serverfault.com) ) - or using some programming language - if so: **what** programming language?? What have you done already, where are you stuck??

Comment: Yes, probably I have to write on serverfault. I would like to write with Sun IDM, but I don't know the syntax of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LDIF, you have multiple lines in your modify, with multiple values:

```
memberOf: CN=AAA,OU=AAA,DC=AAA,DC=AAA
memberOf: CN=BBB,OU=BBB,DC=BBB,DC=BBB
memberOf: CN=CCCC,OU=CCC,DC=CCCC
```